# Different Other Linker Flags for two sdk's

Tags: ios, objective-c, build, settings, xcode8

in my project I have to foreign SDKs. The first sdk always work with the flag -ObjC and -all_load and the second doesn't need these flags. If I set the two flags for my second sdk I get some **duplicate symbols** messages. If I remove the flags the first sdk give back the error **unrecognized selector sent to instance**.

How can I fix this problem ? Is there a way to say that the flags -ObjC and -all_load are exclude from the second sdk ?

Edit:
The first sdk is the dropbox iOS sdk and it was installed over pod and need the flags -ObjC and -all_load.

The second sdk have some .h and .m files and a linked library libMTProtocol.a.

If the flags are enabled in other linker flags, I get the following duplicate messages :

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MTExchangeDataThermoFrameFactory in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MTExchangeDataThermoFrameFactory in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._warningHumidity in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._warningDewPoint in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._packetNumber in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._warningAmbTemp in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._timestamp in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._laserOn in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._alarm in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._mode in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._temperatureMode in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._autoSync in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._measID in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._uniqueID in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._component3 in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._component2 in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoInputMessage._component1 in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MTExchangeDataThermoMessageFactory in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MTExchangeDataThermoMessageFactory in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoOutputMessage._packetNumber in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoOutputMessage._syncControl in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MTExchangeDataThermoOutputMessage in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MTExchangeDataThermoOutputMessage in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTExchangeDataThermoOutputMessage._mode in:
ld: 26 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

All duplicate symbols are references on the libMTProtocol.a library.

Comment: More info please. Do you build the SDKs yourself? What duplicate symbols? ...

Comment: The second sdk is the dropbox sdk. It was installed over a pod installation. and the first sdk have .a file and some .h files. The duplicate symbols are **duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$, duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$, duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$** in the first sdk.

Comment: That is the complete error message? Update your question and put all availible information in there to get faster and better answers.